# MySQL Power Outage Affecting MySQL Server - Shuts Down On Its Own

Tags: mysql, windows

I am new to dealing with mysql settings and admin type issues.  About 4-5 hours ago, I had two power outages within 30 minutes of eachother.  As a result, my computer shutdown both times, while in the middle of what I can only assume was a around 20-30 commands on mysql at the time.  After the first, mysql was unaffected.  But after the second, something happened.  MySQL Server cannot remain open for more than a few seconds at a time (before the outage, this was not a problem).  **I am running MySQL Server 5.1.**

I can manually start MySQL server using the admin command line (I am running this on Windows): net start mysql.  I get a message saying "The MySQL service was started successfully".  Then I run a command or (max) two, and then again everything stops working with a 2013 "Lost connection to MYSQL server during query".  Then I have to do restart the MySQL Server all over again.

I have some important data in the database which I cannot reach because the connection times out before I can get it out.  Is there a way I can fix this connection problem easily?  I know my data is in there, because I have gotten a fair amount of it out.

Any help would be appreciated.  Please let me know what other information you might need, and how I can get it.  I have been trying to find the error log for mysql, and have not found it yet.

And, yes, if I get through this, and even if I dont, I will make sure to create a system to update the data on a regular basis so these types of failures aren't so catastrophic in the future.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suited to superuser ?

Comment: Can you show SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G result?

Comment: Perhaps you could try copying the data files to another machine, where there would be a fresh mysql installation...

Comment: Can you post some log files / error codes? It's hard to tell what the error is without any process information.

Comment: I was thinking about shutting down the mysql server process and copying the data directory as you normally do when copying folders around. My thinking was that if the installation became broken for some reason, you could try by having the db files served by a working mysql install on another machine...

Comment: Ryebread, I would love to post log files and error codes, but I can't find them.  How do I get them.  I have no idea why the server is shutting down, but would love to figure it out.  I dont get an error code in my windows command line, it just shuts down without telling me.  Marcello, great idea, I will start looking into that now.

Comment: Marcello, I would love to copy the data, but the connection times arent long enough to do that. These connections seem to stay open for less than a second, and some of these tables take longer than that to pull the data from. @StanMcGeek, the processlist is: Id: 1, User: root, Host, localhost:1397, db: None, Command: Query, Time: 0, State: None, Info: show processlist. Interestingly, when I ran this same thing a minute ago from the same computer, it said localhost:1370. Not sure if that means anything, when I run commands on another mysql on another computer, the local host does not change  .

Comment: @ryebread, I have found two files, called ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1, they are .fmr files, would they contain error logs?  If so, do you know how I can access them in text?

Comment: @NeilAggarwal - then it'd probably be easier to physically copy data on fresh MySQL server. Just copy FRM, MYD and MYI files to another instance. And check PID of your mysqld process - probably it's constantly restarting which is causing connection drops.

Comment: @StanMcGeek, do you think this is a problem with MySQL Server only?  If so, do you think I can uninstall MySQL server, and reinstall it, without having to move/copy the actual database files?

Comment: You can find the error logs and configuration information from the online MySQL Manual here:

**Error Log:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html

**General Troubleshooting:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-troubleshooting.html

Comment: belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com
Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community